# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails Spring JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have this query

```html
     DELETE
     FROM bookings as b
     WHERE b.check_out = CURRENT_DATE;
```

and I get

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`online_booking_app`.`booked_rooms`, CONSTRAINT `FK3x1lpikb2vk75nx41lxhdicvn` FOREIGN KEY (`booking_id`) REFERENCES `bookings` (`id`))

My Booking entity has  CascadeType.ALL and mapped by matches the other side - from my research these are some of the mistakes that could lead to this message.

Here is the BookingEntity:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
public class BookingEntity extends BaseEntity {


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "booking",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<BookedRoomsEntity> bookedRooms = new ArrayList<>();

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
        public List<BookedRoomsEntity> getBookedRooms() {
        return bookedRooms;
    }

    public BookingEntity setBookedRooms(List<BookedRoomsEntity> bookedRooms) {
        this.bookedRooms = bookedRooms;
        return this;
    }
```

BookedRoomsEntity

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "booked_rooms")
public class BookedRoomsEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne()
    private BookingEntity booking;
    
    
        public BookingEntity getBooking() {
        return booking;
    }

    public BookedRoomsEntity setBooking(BookingEntity booking) {
        this.booking = booking;
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CascadeType` does only apply to `EntityManager` operations.

You therefore have two options:

- Load the entities to be deleted first and then use [`EntityManager.remove`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)
- Remove the referencing entities first with a separate JPQL statement.